# How can I unit test grails service which is using methods from a plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, plugins

I've got a service, which is using sendJMSMessage method which is provided by jms-grails plugin.
I want to write some unit tests, but I'm not sure how to "mock" this method, so it just does nothing at all.
Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can metaClass the method to have it return whatever you want.

```
@Test
void pluginCode() {
    def myService = new MyService()
    def wasCalled = false
    myService.metaClass.sendJMSMessage = {String message ->
        //I like to have an assert in here to test what's being passed in so I can ensure wiring is correct
        wasCalled = true
        null //this is what the method will now return
    }

    def results = myService.myServiceMethodThatCallsPlugin()

    assert wasCalled
}
```

I like to have a `wasCalled` flag when I'm returning `null` from a metaClassed method because I don't particularly like asserting that the response is `null` because it doesn't really assure that you're wired up correctly.  If you're returning something kind of unique though you can do without the `wasCalled` flag.

In the above example I used 1 String parameter but you can `metaClass` out any number/type of parameters to match what actually happens.

Comment: Hi Jarred, unfortunately the method is not on a service. It's something "exposed" on my service by the plugin. Not entirely sure how it works, as I've never tried writing plugins, but I can simply call this method "out of nowhere".

Comment: Then they are probably metaClassing it on to all services (possible controllers and domain objects).  You can simply metaClass it on your service then.  I'll update my answer.